# Scale matrix in place

Tags: java, android, matrix, opengl-es, scale

currently I am scaling a matrix like so:

```
public void scale(float aw, float ah){
    Matrix.scaleM(modelMatrix, 0, aw, ah, 1f);
    updateMVP();
}

private void updateMVP(){
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mvpMatrix, 0, projectionMatrix, 0, modelMatrix, 0);
}
```

And using: `gl_Position = u_Matrix * a_Position;` in my vertex shader, `u_Matrix` being the `mvpMatrix`. The camera I am using is the default and the `projectionMatrix` is created by:

```
ASPECT_RATIO = (float) height / (float) width;
orthoM(projectionMatrix, 0, -1f, 1f, -ASPECT_RATIO, ASPECT_RATIO, -1f, 1f);
```

Now I can scale my object properly, but the only problem is that every time I scale the matrix, the object moves a little bit. I was wondering how I could scale the matrix while keeping the center point and not having the object translate. Anyone know how I can do this in OpenGL ES 2.0 on Android? Thanks

Comment: From the shown code I can only guess: Are you keeping the matrices for translation, rotation and scaling separate? If not, you can only scale the already transformed object/matrix

Comment: Currently I have only the modelMatrix, which I first translate and then scale it multiple times

Comment: Scaling is relative to the origin. You usually first scale (relative to the object's space) and then translate. If you want to change the scaling, you need to make a new modelMatrix, not multiply to the current one, and then apply everything again.

Comment: I only translate once, where I want the object origin to be

Comment: @Felk even if I set the model matrix to identity then scale, the object still translates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have any other matrices (rotation/translation)?

**If so:** you might not be multiplying your matrices in the correct order, which can cause issues.

(proper order multiply right to left)
Translate * Rotation * Scale

Your error sounds like the one explained here:

> You translate the ship by (10,0,0). Its center is now at 10 units of the origin.
>   You scale your ship by 2. Every coordinate is multiplied by 2 relative to the origin, which is far away… So you end up with a big
>   ship, but centered at 2*10 = 20. Which you don’t want.

http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-3-matrices/

Comment: So your telling me I need to reset my model matrix, scale it, rotate it then translate it every time I need to scale it?

Comment: Or are you saying that I need to have three matrices for each operation, and then multiply them together to get the model matrix?

Comment: Scaling needs to be at the origin to work properly, so yes you have to do the translate calculations over again. I do not think rotation interferes with scaling though, but I'm not 100% sure. You can combine all the matrices together if you want to do it all in one calculation, but they still have to be in the right order.

Comment: You mean "translation" where you say "transformation"? All of scaling, rotation, and translation are types of transformations. Also, this looks backwards. With this order of multiplications, the scaling is applied last. At least if you multiply vectors from the right, which is by far the most common order.

Comment: Yes, I meant translate. I got the two mixed up, and I think I typed it left to right because on the site it had it in the correct order but under it said "!!! BEWARE !!! This lines actually performs the scaling FIRST, and THEN the rotation, and THEN the translation. This is how matrix multiplication works.", so I must have typed it after the way I read it. I'll fix that.

Comment: Ok, if I only scale the matrix then it still seems to move away from the origin when I scale it

Comment: It might be the matrix you're using. Anything in the blue that isn't 0 (minus the bottom one) will cause the matrix to move http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/images/Matrix3Delements.jpg  It should look like this: http://what-when-how.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/tmpD71_thumb2.jpg

Comment: Nope, after scaling the last coordinates are the same. The project matrix: http://imgur.com/fZ42jjM the MVP matrix after scaling by 1.0001: http://imgur.com/uXM4oe5

Comment: Hmm... Maybe the negative -1.0 in the scalar is throwing it off. I'll test

Comment: The -1.0 turns an object inside out. It seems like the project matrix is just rescaling it, so I'm not sure what's causing it to shift. I can only assume it's something like a translation matrix somehow being applied before your calculations, or some sort of other issue.

Comment: Thats is the only thing I am doing to the matrix, which is being passed in and then multiplied by the `vec4` of the point.

Comment: The weird thing is that scaling seems to work properly for other objects, and even after completely rewriting the class it is the exact same problem.